# RPi 4 First Boot: Blank TV Screen and SD card become "RCOVERY" with MBR, READ OLNY

Tags: pi-4

It's my first experience with the Raspberry Pi. I bought RPi B 4 with 2GB RAM, before starting off I go through RPi videos, tutorial and finally loaded Noobs into 16GB Sandisk memory card. I plugged everything according to online tutorials and when I powered it on got a blank screen on my TV. After that when I removed SD-Card it was titled as RECOVERY. I tried various methods available on the Internet to format it but didn't get success. I found RPi partition the card into "boot" and "recovery" but in my case, only "recovery" partition is there. some sources say to display through HDMI port of the TV, changes are needed in "config.txt" but I couldn't find the same on the SD-Card.

Via partition manager, my SD card shows (14.83 GB, Basic, MBR, Read-only, USB)
1. Around 2 GB of RECOVERY
2. Around 12 GB of unallocated space, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Can anybody guide me on what to do?
Do I have to go with a new card? Or any problem with my Pi 4?
Please help me out.

Note: Noobs version 3.2.1 used, HDMI port 1 used.

Comment: Those MBR flags are completely ignored by the Raspberry Pi boot loader. NOOBS always renames the first primary partition to "RECOVERY" that's part of how it works. So you can ignore that too.

Answer (score 1):

Flash 'Raspbian with Desktop' (don't unzip) to sd card with Etcher.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

https://www.balena.io/etcher/

On a Pi4 use hdmi0 (next to power connector).

Comment: Thanks. Will try soon. But what about my current SD card (MBR, read only)? It is not getting formatted. Have to go with new one?

Comment: Etcher should overwrite the sd card, unless the sd card has died.